# ImportError: No module named tensorflow.keras.applications

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to solve my error about some tensorflow packages I've already installed bu I don't understand what doesn't work. Please help.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.applications import Xception # TensorFlow ONLY
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
```

And here's my error

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
ImportError: No module named tensorflow.keras.applications
```

And here are my packages' versions

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'2.9.1'

>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.keras.__version__)
'2.9.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
`from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet`

or try downgrading to tensorflow 2.7

`!pip uninstall tensorflow`

`!pip install tensorflow==2.7`

Comment: I've got this
```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.7 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.7
```

Comment: Thank you. I just solved my problem. it was about the run code. I've got python3 and not python.